# Programs that run using XULRunner

Tags: xulrunner, xul

Thanks to another question of mine here on Superuser, I was pointed in the direction of XULRunner, which allows me to run Chatzilla without making having to install the addon for firefox: http://chatzilla.rdmsoft.com/xulrunner/

Which has the obvious benefit that I no longer face the problem that when I close Firefox, chatzilla closes too.

I'm wondering, are there more programs that run on XULRunner, that you use? Tell me about them.

Comment: Community wiki?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A long but not complete list of applications on xulrunner can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner_Hall_of_Fame)

Comment: the link is at mozilla.org is dead. However a copy is here https://web.archive.org/web/20120520115729/https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner_Hall_of_Fame

Answer (score 0):

All Mozilla applications use XULRunner including [Firefox](http://www.firefox.com), [Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/), [Seamonkey](http://www.seamonkey-project.org/), [Sunbird](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/sunbird/). Some other popular applications are [Songbird](http://getsongbird.com), [Miro](http://getmiro.com/) and [Joost](http://www.joost.com/)

There's a game based on XUL called [Simon the Sorcerer 4: Chaos Happens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_the_Sorcerer_4:_Chaos_Happens)

XUL based applications are cross-platform. The drawback being some of them might be slow on performance esp. start-up time can be a bit longer.

Comment: Yeah, but to run Chatzilla, I had to use the XULrunner.exe program to make it stand-alone.